# What is the relationship between tsconfig.json and gulp.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, asp.net-core, tsconfig

I have an `ASP.NET Core` web app and have some confusion over the relationship between the `TypeScript` responsibilities between `tsconfig.json` and `gulp.js`. As I understand it there seems to be overlapping functionality. For example I can have the following `tsconfig.json` settings:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
}
```

As you see I can specify the `compileOnSave` which defaults to `true` as stated in [documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md) and discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2326). I can set this value to `false` and then use `gulp.js` to issue build, uglify, concat, sourcemaps, etc. However the `tsconfig.json` file *also* offers similar functionality, but it appears to me to be a subset of what `gulp` allows.

I'm not sure where to draw the line as a `VS.NET` user. Should I allow `tsconfig.json` compile my `.ts.` to `.js` and then let `gulp.js` take care of all the other requirements such as file copying, concat, uglify, etc.?

It appears to me there is redundant functionality and I'm getting confused as to the relationship and how to manage the responsibilities of both files. This came up because I need source map files for my `.ts` for the debugger and I'm not sure which file should be responsible.

Can someone help me clear up the relationship between these files and when to use in reference to my question?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is do what works for you, if you like having your `.ts` compiled as you go then do that otherwise don't.

My personal opinion would be to **not** compile your `.ts` as you go and set up a gulp task to transpile as part of your asset building (i.e. transpile sass, minifiy). My reasoning is that the `.js` files are generated and therefore can be recreated on the fly as part of a build pipeline and do not need to be included in your solution.

Comment: If I go this route, does this mean `tsconfig.json` is not even required, and _everything_ can be done via tasks in `gulp`?

Comment: @atconway I am not super familiar with all the options in `.tsconfig` however if the only options you have set are related to compilation and creating a sourcemap, I would say yes.